# Elasticsearch - How can I only get "English" results only when searching for "English" words?

Tags: elasticsearch

My site has one index with a language detector to switch between Spanish or English. I want to be able to search in english and only get english results. And same for searching in Spanish. The code that handles the mapping/translation can be found here: https://github.com/Automattic/wpes-lib

I'm new to Elasticsearch, but have been learning for about a month. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

I tried (below i'm using PHP syntax):

```
"must_not" => [
    "match" => [
        "query" => $query,
        "field" => "title.es"       
    ]
],
```

and:

```
"must_not" => [
    "match" => [
        "title.es" => [
          "query" => $query
        ]
     ]
],
```

Full query below:

```
$es_query_args['query']['function_score']['query']['bool'] = [
    "must" => [
      "multi_match" => [
        "query" => $query,
        "type" => "best_fields",
        "fields" => [
          "meta.search_content.value",
          "taxonomy.search_tag.name",
          "title"
        ],
        "fuzziness" => "auto",
        "operator" => "and",
        "tie_breaker" => 0.3
      ],
    ],
     "must_not" => [
       "match" => [
         "query" => $query,
         "fields" => ["title.es"]     
       ]
     ],
    "should" => [
      "multi_match" => [
        "query" => $query,
        "fields" => [
          "title^3", 
          "taxonomy.search_tag.name^3",
          "meta.search_content.value",
        ],
        "fuzziness" => "auto",
        "type" => "phrase",
        "slop" => 5,
      ],
    ],
  ];
```

with no luck :(

Comment: are those your full queries? if not, could you please provide your full query?

Comment: I updated my question with my full search query.